# Missing return statement Android

Tags: android, json

I have implemented a ListView in a Fragment. Now I am getting the error `'missing return statement'` after the

```
new GetSloten().execute();
 }
```

Need help

This is my code:

```
public class SlotenFragment extends ListFragment {

private ProgressDialog nDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://charlenemacdonald.com/sloten.json";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SLOTEN = "slotenlijst";
private static final String TAG_SLOT = "Slot";


// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray sloten= null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> slotenLijst;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    slotenLijst = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String Slot = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewslotnaam))
                    .getText().toString();


            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    SlotInfoScherm1.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_SLOT, Slot);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetSloten().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetSloten extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        nDialog.setMessage("Even geduld a.u.b., studenten worden geladen...");
        nDialog.setCancelable(false);
        nDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                sloten = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_SLOTEN);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < sloten.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = sloten.getJSONObject(i);

                    String Slot = c.getString(TAG_SLOT);


                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> sloten = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    sloten.put(TAG_SLOT, Slot);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    slotenLijst.add(sloten);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (nDialog.isShowing())
            nDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                SlotenFragment.this, slotenLijst,
                R.layout.sloten_info, new String[] { TAG_SLOT}, new int[] { R.id.textviewslotnaam});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}



    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sloten, container, false);

    return rootView;


}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the error states, you have to return something from your onCreateView method.

Comment: I know that, but can you give me a suggestion? Because I'm out of options. @X.L.Ant

Comment: Clean up your code and indent correctly and you'll find the error. Look at the end of your code... there's a `return rootView` "floating" around - it should probably not be there... where should it go? :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` requires that you return a `View` object. You should most certainly return the view for your Fragment as below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String Slot = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewslotnaam))
                .getText().toString();


            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                SlotInfoScherm1.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_SLOT, Slot);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    //Return your view
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally you should inflate a `view` in `onCreateView()`, find all the views of interest from it, and return it at the end of method.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
   ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
   // .......

   return view;
}
```

This is how you did:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

if so, then you may return `lv`.

But I doubt this is the correct way, as `getView()` returns the root view for the fragments layout, which you didn't inflate. I can see a `NullPointerException` at that line, if you return `lv`.